# NSPredicate syntax for DATEADD?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

is there a way to do a DateAdd or a DateDiff function on an NSPredicate?
Thank you,
Jose.

Comment: +1, but man and I was going to do a blog post on figuring this out... thanks for stealing my thunder :P ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, there is!  It's a roundabout way of doing it, because `NSPredicate` doesn't support it directly (ie, you can't just `+ anInterval` to an `NSDate`).  Fortunately, you can do it, and luckily for you, I just figured it out about 2 days ago.

To clarify: I'm assuming you're asking for something like: "an object has a `date` property.  I want to see if this `date` property is some arbitrary interval before/after another date".  If that's what you mean, then yes you can do it.  If that's not what you mean, then please clarify your question.

Here we go.  In this example, we're going to assume the object against which we'll be evaluating this predicate has a property called `date` that returns an `NSDate`.  We are going to see if this date is at least 1 day before another date.  There are a couple different ways we could do this comparison:

```
date + 1 day is before comparisonDate
date is before comparisonDate - 1 day
```

I'm going to go with the first approach:

```
NSDate * comparisonDate = ...; //an arbitrary NSDate object, against which we're going to be doing our comparison
NSTimeInterval interval = 86400; //the number of seconds you want add or subtract.

NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CAST(CAST(date, 'NSNumber') + %f, 'NSDate') < %@", interval, comparisonDate];
```

What's going on:

To get this to work, we can `CAST()` a date object to an `NSNumber`.  This is going to convert the `NSDate` into an `NSNumber` which is some number of seconds from a reference point in time (such as 1 Jan 1970 or whatever).  To that number we add or subtract our interval, and then cast the new number back to an `NSDate`.  Then we can use a regular comparison operator to compare our new date against our comparison date.

There are a couple different variations on this idea, but they all require casting an `NSDate` to a number (or casting a number to an `NSDate`) to get its time interval.

Devious, eh?

**edit**

If Core Data is complaining about the construct of the predicate, try reversing things:

```
NSDate * comparisonDate = ...;
NSTimeInterval interval = 86400;

NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date < CAST(CAST(%@, 'NSNumber') - %f, 'NSDate')", comparisonDate, interval];
```

**edit #2**

The thunder that The Reverend stole: http://tumblr.com/xqorqjfrz

Comment: Dave thanks a lot man, and don't cancel the blog on my account.. I'm curious to know how you came up with this solution?

Comment: Unfortunatley it didnt work for coredata, when setting the predicate to the entity I get a "function not supported" exception...

Comment: I tried both forms of creating the NSPredicate but neither of them seem to work. Even for the simplest possible expression, it seems to throw an error:

NSPredicate * pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"now() != 0"];
  Keep getting "* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported function expression now()'"

Comment: This is very clever, but why wouldn't you just adjust the comparison date +/- 1 day and avoid that mess, e.g. instead of comparing tomorrow (today + 1 day) to 30 days ago, just compare today to 31 days ago. Then it just becomes a simple predicate comparison [... @"date < %@", oldDate].