# Fetching time related data which includes current time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have data stored where one of the entity's attributes is `startTime` which is stores as an NSNumber (NSTimeInterval) and another attribute with the item's `duration`.

How would I go about fetching the single item which is valid for "now" - i.e. teh item who's start time + duration includes the current time ([NSDate date])?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this SO question: [NSPredicate syntax for DATEADD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170996/nspredicate-syntax-for-dateadd)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `NSDateFormatter` to grab the current time/date and then use `NSDateComponents` to break this into hours/mins/seconds (as required).

Then increment your startTime and duration onto it.

Then use the components to create a new `NSDate` which will be your result.

Comment: Is there no way of making a predicate where time lies between startTime and startTime + duration?