# FetchedResultsController with transient attribute for comparing dates

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a JOURNEY entity in CoreData. It has arrivalDate and departureDate as attributes.

arrivalDate and departureDate both are of type NSDate?

I want to fetch only those journey whose duration is more than an hour.

To achieve this I created a transient attribute in my Journey+CoreDataClass

```
public var isJourneyLongEnough: Bool{
    if let arrival = arrivalDate as Date?, let departure = departureDate as Date?{
        let duration = departure.timeIntervalSince(arrival)
        return duration >= 3600 ? true : false
    } else{
        return false
    }
}
```

When I tried fetching it crashes with an error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath isJourneyLongEnough not found in entity.

On researching more about this issue I figured out that we can't use transient property in predicate as these doesn't exist when fetching managed objects from persistentStore.

> You cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties (although you can use transient properties to filter in memory yourself). ... To summarize, though, if you execute a fetch directly, you should typically not add Objective-C-based predicates or sort descriptors to the fetch request. Instead you should apply these to the results of the fetch.

What is the best way to achieve this? I am using a FetchedResultsController to display all journeys in a UITableView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamps are stored as seconds (since the reference date Jan 1, 2001)
in the Core Data SQLite file, and one can simply check if the difference between
departure and arrival date is at least 3600 seconds:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "arrivalDate - departureDate >= 3600")
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```

This worked as expected in my test. If the minimal journey duration
is determined at runtime, use

```
let minDuration = 3600
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "arrivalDate - departureDate >= %@", minDuration as NSNumber)
```

*Remark:* The above predicates work only if used in a Core Data
fetch request. The following variant works both with Core Data
fetch requests and with directly evaluated predicates:

```
 NSPredicate(format: "arrivalDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - departureDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate >= 3600")
```

Comment: I have tried your approach for subtracting the dates it worked when fetching the results.
A day later, the app started crashing when new objects where added to Database.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'mathematical functions require NSNumber parameters'

I will need to cast it to NSNumber I guess

Comment: @FE_Tech: Have you tried the other approach (with timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)?

Comment: Yes, with timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate approach, None of my journeys fetched. I am not getting any object from Database. And my TableView is empty.

Comment: @FE_Tech: It worked in my test, but I will double-check it later. Otherwise I do not have a better idea at the moment, sorry.

Comment: using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate is working. The issue was something else for me.
I have no idea why first approach causes crash when new objects were added.
But with this timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate is working even when new objects are added.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following NSPredicate, it‘s based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170996/nspredicate-syntax-for-dateadd) and essentially casts the dates to NSNumber, subtracts them and then compares the result to be bigger or smaller than 3600 seconds.

I haven‘t tried it, but maybe it helps. The original question was in ObjC though, so maybe some things changed.

```
NSPredicate(format: “departureDate != nil AND arrivalDate != nil AND CAST(departureDate, ‘NSNumber‘) - CAST(arrivalDate, ‘NSNumber‘) >= 3600“)
```

Comment: I tried this way also, but it is giving me error.
CoreData: error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x105972c30> , Unsupported function expression CAST(departureDate, "NSNumber") - CAST(arrivalDate, "NSNUmber") with userInfo of (null)

Comment: arrivalDate and departureDate are optional in JOURNEY entity.
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "arrivalDate != nil AND departureDate != nil AND (CAST(departureDate, 'NSNumber') - CAST(arrivalDate, 'NSNUmber')) >= 3600")

Comment: This is the error which I am getting while crash*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported function expression CAST(departureDate, "NSNumber") - CAST(arrivalDate, "NSNUmber")'

Comment: Maybe arrivalDate or departureDate are nil? In that case you can filter those out, I edited my answer for it. You could also make them required in CoreData so it crashes on save incase they are not set.